# Accessing X Display through Apache

Tags: php, python, linux, apache

I am trying to send keypresses to a Raspberry Pi running Raspdbian from from a web page hosted on an Apache server at `/var/www`.

I'm using `xdotool`, which can send keypresses using commands like this:

```
xdotool key C
```

I made a python script `xdotool.py` that sends a few keypresses like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

print 'sending HI'
os.system("export DISPLAY=:0")
os.system("xdotool key H")
os.system("xdotool key I")
```

I am SSH'd into the Raspberry as user Pi, and running this script from terminal works fine and sends the keystrokes "HI" to the Raspberry.

However, I want to be able to do this through a web page. I've made a php-script that runs python scripts and displays the terminal output in the browser, but it does not work with the xdotool.py script. I have given the script permission to be viewed/changed/executed by all users.

I've also changed the Apache settings in `/etc/apache2/envvars` and changed the user from www-data to pi. The user pi should have all necessary permissions.

The script does run, and "sending HI" is displayed in the browser. But it doesn't send the keystrokes. The error I get from `error.log` is this:

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? If there's a way to give everyone permission to do everything, that wouldn't be a problem seeing that this server will only run on a local network with no internet access.

Comment: "it does not work" never helped anyone anywhere at any time. What does that mean? Do you get an error? Maybe in the error log file? What do you get on the front side, so in your browser? Anything in the system log? What are the permissions of your script? What is the user account your http server executes the php script with? Is the python script executed at all? Did you really check that?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question and provided some actual information and errors

Comment: OK, so it looks like your issue is the permission to access the running x server. Indeed that is only allowed to the owner of the x server, _except_ if you take special steps. You want to read about access control in X servers. Start with the man page of the xhost utility: `man xhost`